# One Custom Post Type two different Templates

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, templates, permalinks

I have a custom post type with some metaboxes, for this CPT have his own single-CPT.php where I show his content and metaboxes and url domain.com/CPT.
But what I need to know is if posible to create a second template where I only show the metaboxes content of this CPT and url domain.com/CPT/metaboxes

Hope it make sence and have a solution :P

Thanx to all.

Comment: Are you talking about like when you can select a template like you do in a drop down for page templates? For example: One post type with more than one template to choose from. Or just a default template that only this custom post type is going to be using?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You'll have to write a custom rewrite rule for making the `domain.com/cpt/metaboxes` url to be accessible. Lets say your cpt is 'movie', its single will be accessible as `domain.com/movie/slug`. Create a new page named 'Metaboxes' (slug should be 'metaboxes'). Add the following code to functions.php.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');

function add_my_rule()
{
    global $wp_rewrite, $wp;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('^movie/([^/]+)/metaboxes', 'index.php?pagename=metaboxes&movie_slug=$matches[1]', 'top');
    $wp->add_query_var('movie_slug');
}
?>
```

After you add this code, go to `Settings > Permalinks` and just hit save (don't miss this step!). Make sure you have pretty permalinks turned on.

Next step is to access the `movie_slug` on this page. Create a template which will show the metaboxes content and assign this template to the `Metaboxes` page created above. Add the following code to this template:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Metaboxes
 */

//this will give you the cpt slug.
$slug = get_query_var('movie_slug');

//now we get the cpt object using the slug
$args=array(
    'name' => $slug,
    'post_type' => 'movie',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'showposts' => 1,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);

$movie = get_posts($args);

//we need only the ID
$movie_id = $movie[0]->ID;

//Use the $movie_id to get all the metaboxes content, means the post meta/custom values and build your markup around it.
?>
```

I haven't tried this, but I'm sure it will work with a minor tweaks. Let me know if you are stuck or face any errors.